# Calendário javascript com scroll horizontal

Tags: javascript, rolamento, calendar, horizontal

estou procurando algum calendário javascript gratuito, parecido com o que tem no mobiscroll (https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/calendar/week-view#), com apenas uma semana visível e com scroll horizontal. Alguém tem uma indicação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Você pode pegar o código fonte desse calendario no próprio site..

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não consegui... eles vendem o componente. Só achei meio caro... 99,00 dólares

Comment: Tente https://github.com/chrisdavies/tiny-date-picker o melhor responsivo e editável, apenas 3,5Kb gzipado [DEMO](https://chrisdavies.github.io/tiny-date-picker/)